# create a stack in java

Tags: java, vector, stack

I need to use stack to create a list storing objects, and I try to look up in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), however, I have no idea which is the syntax I should refer to.

Here is my code:

```
public class Rock {
public String name;

public Rock(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
}



public class RockTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Rock r1 = new Rock("eluanshi");
    Rock r2 = new Rock("jingangshi");
    Rock r3 = new Rock("dalishi");
    Stack(r1,r2,r3); // this is obviously wrong but how can i deal with it
}



 }
```

Comment: "I need to use stack to create a list storing objects" Well, do you need a `Stack`, or a `List`?. Pick one.

Comment: Don't jump into a language doing random things. Follow a tutorial and understand what you're doing.

Comment: This is Java, not C++. Please follow a tutorial. You can start with the [official Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: if using stack then instantiate new stack and use method `stack.push(Object)` if using List then instantiate ArrayList and use `list.add(Object)`

Comment: By the way, you should not use `java.util.Stack` class since it extends from `Vector` which is technically deprecated and highly discouraged to use. Instead, use a [`java.util.Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (double ended queue) which behaves as both queue and stack, the client class defines the behavior. This is an interface, so you may use [`java.util.ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)

Comment: @user3580294 I had this worry when I was typing my problem, so stack is extended from vector which belongs to List interface, which means List includes Stack?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am very sorry if my question is so dumb, actually I am trying to write a little program to understand these concepts better! However, thank you for the kind suggestion i will take notes.

Comment: @ZoeH While true, generally you use `List`s and `Stack`s to store things for different purposes. It's generally not advisable to use one for the other because of that, which is why you usually hear programmers wanting a "stack of _____" or "list of _____" but never "stack for a list of ____"

Comment: @ZoeH: What do you mean with "includes". Extends means that every `Stack` is some kind of `List` in the abstract sense: a list is a collection of items where some items might occur more than once and with some kind of order (top-to-bottom in the case of a `Stack`).

Comment: @ZoeH the question itself is not dumb, just shows that you're learning Java language. Also, it is a good opportunity to learn good stuff as not using `Vector` class or any of their subclasses since `Stack` extends from `Vector`.

Comment: @CommuSoft `Stack` doesn't extend `List`, it implements it.

Comment: True that. Although some argue (like C#) that extending and implementing are the same thing. That's why C# uses a colon for both. I.e.: `class Foo : Bar, IBaz`

Comment: @CommuSoft sure, but this is Java, not another programming language :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack is a generic type, and it only has a constructor with no arguments. You need to `push` your data on the stack:

```
Stack<Rock> stack = new Stack<Rock>();//use new Stack<>() in Java 7 (diamond inference)
stack.push(r1);
stack.push(r2);
stack.push(r3);
```

This will result in a stack with `r3` on top. You can reverse the `push` instructions if you want `r1` on top.

---

The generics (the `<>` part) specifies the type of elements your stack will contain. If you use `Rock` (like in the above example), you can only push rocks on the stack. The advantage is however that you are sure that when you `pop` an element, it's a rock. If you for instance want to create a stack with several elements (`String`,...) you can use object:

```
Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.push(r1);//rock at the bottom
stack.push("Second item");
stack.push(r2);
stack.push((Integer) 2);
stack.push("Four elements already");
stack.push(r3);
```

The disadvantage of this is of course that you cannot determine at compile time the type of element you will pop from the stack.

---

You can iterate over an `Stack` using the `Stack<T>.iterator` method:

```
Stack<Rock> stack = new Stack<Rock>();
stack.push(r1);
stack.push(r2);
stack.push(r3);
Iterator<Rock> iter = stack.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Rock r = iter.next();
    //do something with the current rock
}
```

In modern versions of Java (probably since Java 7) you can use a foreach-construct:

```
Stack<Rock> stack = new Stack<Rock>();
stack.push(r1);
stack.push(r2);
stack.push(r3);
for(Rock r : stack) {
    //do something with the current rock
}
```

Notice that an iterator for a stack works top-to-bottom. So `r3` will be iterated first.

Comment: The diamond operator `<>` was introduced in Java 7, not Java 5. But otherwise good answer!

Comment: Indeed, sorry, sometimes I mix programming language versions up. Will fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @CommuSoft the content below horizon is very helpful, by the way how do I iterate through stack? also using Iterator method? But it seems I only get package class name @ hashcode